# Fill in a text field with a file system path

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an HTML form and one the pieces of data we are collecting is a folder location.  Right now the users have to manually input the path.  I've been asked to make this easier.  My thought was to provide a file input field, and have the user select a file in the needed folder, and then use javascript to parse the full file system path, and populate the other field.  The product owners seemed to like that idea.
Since I have been trying to come up with some javascript to do this, and haven't been very successful.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This information is deliberately inaccessible for security reasons.

Comment: More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357261/how-to-get-fullname-with-path-info-in-firefox-using-asp-net-upload-control